# Subsequence in a sequence of numbers in scala

Tags: scala

For example i have:
`List(1,3,2,5)`

How i get all these:
`List(1), List(3), List(2), List(5), List(1,3), List(1,2), List(1,5), List(3,2), List(3,5), List(2,5), List(1,3,2), List(1,3,5), List(1,2,5), List(3,2,5), List(1,3,2,5))`

I need this for Longest Increasing Subsequence -problem and this answer for example would be: (1,3,5)

And I want use it for bigger Lists.

Comment: To avoid confusion you need to be more explicit about exactly what you want. So give a verbal description of the output that you want rather than just an example, or provide multiple examples with a wider variety of inputs.

Comment: I put better example. I hope it makes clear. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I just miss it.

Comment: The output you've posted for the new example is exactly the output from my answer. It's still not clear what you want that the suggested answers don't supply.

Comment: Example for List(0, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 4) it doesn't give me List(0,2,3,4) in that order.

Answer (score 6):

You want all the `combinations()` from 1 to array length.

```
val arr = Array(4, 3, 1)

arr.indices.flatMap(x => arr.combinations(x + 1))
//res0: Seq[Array[Int]] = Vector(Array(4), Array(3), Array(1), Array(4, 3), Array(4, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 3, 1))
```

---

**update**

This will give you all possible combinations, retaining original order and duplicate elements.

```
def subseqs[A](seq :Seq[A]) :List[Seq[A]] = seq match {
  case hd +: tl =>
    val res = subseqs(tl)
    Seq(hd) :: res ++ res.map(hd +: _)
  case Seq() => Nil
}
```

The result is a `List` of n^2 - 1 possible sub-sequences. So for a collection of 8 elements you'll get 255 sub-sequences.

This, of course, is going to be *way* too tedious and inefficient for your purposes. Generating all possible sub-sequences in order to find the Longest Increasing is a little like washing all the clothes in your neighborhood so you'll have clean socks in the morning.

Much better to generate only the increasing sub-sequences and find the longest from that set (9 lines of code).

Comment: But how i get all orders and correct order not only combinations?

Comment: Your question is unclear. This answer provides all the results you requested in the order specified. Are you saying you also need all _permutations_? (i.e. `3,1,4` and `1,4,3` and ... etc.)

Comment: Yeah permutations and same order like in `Array(4, 3, 1, 2, 3)` It can't  `Array(4, 3, 3,2)`. So it needs to respect order as well. Im using it for longest increasing subsequence problem.

Comment: You are still being unclear. You can't have permutations _and_ preserve order. Permutations means all elements in all possible orders. Again, this answer provides what you asked for, all possible combinations with the original order of the elements preserved. If that's not enough then please edit the question so that it accurately describes what you want.

Comment: `import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._ Seq(1,2,3,7,9).combinations(4).toList.sorted.foreach(println)` Like this but without importing and all combinations 1 to 5.

Comment: The example input, `1,2,3,7,9`, is already sorted so the `import` and the `.sorted` aren't doing anything. They can be removed and you'll get the same result. If you need the results to be sorted then that directly contradicts the example you posted in the question. You should edit the original question, adding a new, small, example where my suggested answer does _not_ provide the desired solution.

Comment: This answer does not produce all the subsequences if the input contains duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

[ Update in response to updated question ]

[ Thanks to @jwvh for spotting error in original version ]

This method will generate all possible sub-sequences of a `List`:

```
def subsequences[T](list: List[T]): List[List[T]] =
  list match {
    case Nil =>
      List(List())
    case hd :: tl =>
      val subs = subsequences(tl)

      subs.map(hd +: _) ++ subs
  }
```

Note that this is not efficient for a number of reasons, so it is not a good way to solve the "longest increasing subsequence problem".

---

[ Original answer ]

This function will generate all the non-empty contiguous sub-sequences of any sequence:

```
 def subsequences[T](seq: Seq[T]) =
   seq.tails.flatMap(_.inits).filter(_.nonEmpty)
```

This returns an `Iterator` so it creates each sub-sequence in turn which reduces memory usage.

Note that this will generate all the sub-sequences and will preserve the order of the values, unlike solutions using `combinations` or `Set`.

---

You can use this in your "longest increasing subsequence problem" like this:

```
def isAscending(seq: Seq[Int]): Boolean =
  seq.length <= 1 || seq.sliding(2).forall(x => x(0) < x(1))

subsequences(a).filter(isAscending).maxBy(_.length)
```

The result will be the longest sequence of ascending values in the input `a`.

Comment: Solution appears to miss some sub-sequences. From a collection of 8 elements there is only 1 sub-seq (instead of 8) of length 1, and only 7 (instead of 28) of length 2.

Comment: @jwvh Thanks, I got the termination condition wrong :( I have now fixed it and it looks much more plausible!